# how to loop animation a few times or a few seconds?

Tags: ios, animation, loops, time

I found a few questions that are related, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034327/moving-an-object-randomly-around-the-screen), but I still need a little bit help here.
What I want is a button, once clicked, flying randomly in either of the following ways:
1, it flies through five random position and flies back to original position. or
2, it flies randomly for 2 seconds, and then back to its original position.

Here is my code, but the stop control is still missing:

```
   //if the button clicked
    [self animationLoop:@"Wrong!" finished:1 context:nil];
    -(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(int)finished context:(void *)context {
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:finished];

   CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
   CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);
   CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
   theWrongButton.center = squarePostion;

   [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
   [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];

  [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

I think my question is kind of like how to loop the animation a few times or a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this:

```
    //in the animation loop
       if (animationLoopCounter > 3) {
        return;
        }

   [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:)];

   - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
   animationLoopCounter++;
   [self animationLoop:@"Wrong!" finished:1 context:nil];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is exactly what the context parameter is used for. It enables you to pass in any object that you can use later. For instance, some like this is what you may be looking for:

```
    [self animationLoop:@"Wrong!" finished:1 context:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
-(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(int)finished context:(void *)context {

    NSNumber *count = (NSNumber *)context;
    if ([count intValue]) >= 5) {
        return;
    }
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]+1]];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:finished];

    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);
    CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
    theWrongButton.center = squarePostion;

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];

   [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
```

Comment: its in `...context:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]+1]`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> 
                     animations:<#^(void)animations#> 
                     completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>];
```

this animation command comes with a completion block.