# Float a UIView around the screen in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

So I'm trying to do a long running animation with some UIViews. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is take a square subview and have it float randomly around the screen in the background (like a leaf floating on a pond). I was hoping to do it with regular animations but so far I've had problems where the animation just stops even with setting the option to begin at the current position. Anyone know of a simple way to do this?

I saw [Moving an object randomly around the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034327/moving-an-object-randomly-around-the-screen) already but isn't that going to eventually cause a stack overflow due to the recursion?

Also, I'm asking how to do this without an added library/framework.

Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you refer to *does not* use any additional frameworks aside from the standard ones in the iOS SDK, and *will not* cause a stack overflow because there is no recursion (The Objective-C delegate method calls won't pile up on the stack since the stack will clear every time).

Comment: Basically, your question is a duplicate of the question that you found.

Comment: So is there a way to close this as a duplicate then or do I just delete the question?

Comment: It'll be closed as a duplicate after enough people flag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code for you:

```
- (CGFloat) distanceBetweenTwoPoints: (CGPoint) point1 : (CGPoint) point2 {
    CGFloat dx = point2.x - point1.x;
    CGFloat dy = point2.y - point1.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
}

#define kMovingSpeed 25 //pixel per second
- (void) floatView : (id) view_{
    UIView *view = (UIView *)view_;
    CGPoint viewCenter = view.center;
    CGPoint nextCenter = CGPointMake(arc4random() % 320, arc4random() % (([self.view bounds].size.height > 480)?568:460));//or chech for orientation as well
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(viewCenter, nextCenter))
        [self floatView:view];

    float distance = [self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:viewCenter :nextCenter];
    double time = distance / kMovingSpeed;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                     animations:^{
                         [view setCenter:nextCenter];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self floatView:view];
                     }];
}
```