# Animation is delayed before starting

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, core-animation

I am using code taken from another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034327/moving-an-object-randomly-around-the-screen) but essentially below is what I am using.  The main problem with this is that when I call it it takes 15 seconds to start then takes 15 seconds to complete each animation. **I want it to start straight away**! What am I missing here?

Called using

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self animationLoop: nil finished:nil context:nil];
}
```

Function

```
-(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:15];

    int padding = _Circle1Container.frame.size.width / 2;

    // Circle 1
    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width + padding);
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height + padding);

    CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
    _Circle1Container.center = squarePostion;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; // as suggested by @Carl Veazey in a comment
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should rename your `_Circle1Container` to `_circle1Container`, as capital letters are usually reserved for `Class` names.

Second, use an animation block to perform your animation, as they are easier to read, and work better. Something like:

```
int padding = _circle1Container.frame.size.width / 2;

// Circle 1
CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width + padding);
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height + padding);

[UIView animateWithDuration:15.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                   _circle1Container.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                   // Fire a completion method here!
                 }];
```

That way, you don't need to pass in all of those other parameters either.

Finally, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your `padding` variable. The range you are generating is `[padding, width+padding]`, and `[padding, height+padding]`. Seems to me like you would want `[padding, width-padding]`, and `[padding, height-padding]`. If that's the case, simply try:

```
#define CLAMP(X, A, B) ((X < A) ? A : ((X > B) ? B : X))

CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % ((int)self.view.bounds.size.width));
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % ((int)self.view.bounds.size.height));
x = CLAMP(x, (CGFloat)padding, (CGFloat)(self.view.bounds.size.width - padding));
y = CLAMP(y, (CGFloat)padding, (CGFloat)(self.view.bounds.size.height - padding));
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I usually use blocks but I copied the code from elsewhere so maybe thats it... Ill try it shortly.  I use the padding to allow my circles to go outside the visible area (but by just enough to hide half of them only)

Comment: On another note - If I call the same function again in the completed handler will it cause a stackoverflow at some point during execution or does it get "posted" back into a message queue during the block?

Comment: Ok... SO that "works" but I still have the massive initial delay!

Comment: The completion handler gets called only once at the end of the animation, so you can call whatever method you like there (even the same one). As for the massive initial delay, there is nothing in the code above that would cause it, so something else must be going on. If you post more code, I can read it over to see what may be causing it.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that I call `[self animationLoop: nil finished:nil context:nil]` initially from within `viewDidLoad` - could this cause an issue?

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!