# Moving object around screen randomly - CoreAnimation? SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, animation

I want to have a small planet floating around the screen while someone is playing my game. I'm a noob so I don't know anything about everything.

Which method would be easiest even if it's not necessarily the best implementation? I checked some YouTube videos about moving objects and it seems everyone was using Obj-C. I want to keep everything within Swift. Would I use CoreAnimation or SpriteKit? I just want to have one png floating slowly around the screen randomly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be a duplicate of the one linked below.  The answer to that question is in objective-C but the properties and methods should all be available in Swift.

To avoid a bouncing effect you can set the start and end points of the animations to be off the screen.

[Moving an object randomly around the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034327/moving-an-object-randomly-around-the-screen?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Sam. So what I'll do is copy the code from the link you sent. Since I'm new to programming I want to get it working then later on I'll convert it to 100% Swift. I have a question about the function. It starts with  -(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {  What does that void mean?  Don't I need to control drag my UIImage "Planet" to viewcontroller.swift? Where should I put the IBOutlet? Do I just leave it declared as a var?

Comment: Hi, I'm using something like this but will delete the collider code since I want it to go through screens. How do I make my object randomly move around the screen and through the screen? What code should I use and where should I put it? Thanks      http://i.imgur.com/fIV0Xp3.png

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use UIKit Dynamics to make an imageview bounce off the sides of the screen. You should be able to keep it bouncing more or less forever once you get it started.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Btw,  since the image is a planet I don't want it to bounce. I would like it to appear and disappear from  random areas on the screen like the asteroids in the Asteroids game. It's the same planet moving off and on the screen. How would I do this?